# Why does my result data returned as void* gets broken?

Tags: c++

I am working in a project with a huge legacy code base and have been trying to re-design parts of it to get away from old c-style code.

I've run into a problem and have prepared a short program to explain.

The legacy interface I am using needs me to pass a pointer to the result data as void* and I would like to avoid having to change this.

The unique_ptr in the example just goes to demonstrate, that in my real code base everything working on the data is using smart pointers to manage memory.

My problem is, that the result data gets broken (see last output line / last call to printPayload); everything is 0 at the end, but it doesn't seem to be a problem with converting to the void* and back as shown by the 2nd and 3rd output line.

Is this a problem related to temporaries?
I don't get it...

I hope this kind of problem has relevance for some of you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Payload
{
    long a;
    int b;
    int c;

    Payload() : a(), b(), c() {}
    Payload(long setA, int setB, int setC) : a(setA), b(setB), c(setC) {}
};

void printPayload(const Payload& printThis)
{
    std::cout << "payload -- a: " << printThis.a << " b: " << printThis.b << " c: " << printThis.c << std::endl;
}

void doSomething(Payload* sourceData, void* targetData)
{
    if (!sourceData) return;

    std::unique_ptr<Payload> sourceDataUnique(sourceData);

    sourceDataUnique->a = 222;
    sourceDataUnique->b = 333;
    sourceDataUnique->c = 444;

    printPayload(*sourceDataUnique);

    targetData = reinterpret_cast<void*>(sourceDataUnique.release());

    printPayload(*(reinterpret_cast<Payload*>(targetData)));
}

int main(void)
{
    Payload* myPayload = new Payload(14, 8, 1982);
    Payload myResult;

    printPayload(*myPayload);

    doSomething(myPayload, &myResult);

    printPayload(myResult);
}
```

Output:

```
payload -- a: 14 b: 8 c: 1982
payload -- a: 222 b: 333 c: 444
payload -- a: 222 b: 333 c: 444
payload -- a: 0 b: 0 c: 0
```

Comment: You set `targetData` in `doSomething`, but this change is local to the function. The parameter should be a reference.

Comment: This can be simplified to: `void doSomething(Payload *src, Payload *dst) { dst = src; }`

Comment: @PankajDaga, that won't work, since it'll be a reference to a temporary.

Comment: Stop using `reinterpret_cast` like that. That's the strongest form of cast there is, and you don't need to use a sledgehammer to convert from `Payload*` to `void*` and back.

Comment: sorry about that cast. I guess a static_cast will do perfectly. However, I feel that a static_cast will look kind of meaningless in a context. where the types have no neccessary relationship. I used reinterpret_cast. to mark up the non-enforced type relation. I guess you don't do that...

Comment: `void*` has a pretty strong type relation with all other pointer types. It really  is okay to "just" `static_cast` those around.

Comment: That interface does not do what you want it to do (pass the address out of the function) you have to change the interface to take a `void*& targetData` or `void** targetData`. Or else return a pointer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`targetData` is a *local* variable to `doSomething`. After you assign an address to it, it goes out of scope.

You never actually assign to `myResult`.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, the parameter `targetData` is local to `doSomething` function (i.e., any change is lost after you exit the scope of the function). However, `*targetData` refers to the variable `myResult` declared in `main` function.

So, the following code should work:

```
void doSomething(Payload* sourceData, void* targetData)
{
    if (!sourceData) return;

    sourceData->a = 222;
    sourceData->b = 333;
    sourceData->c = 444;

    printPayload(*sourceData);

    Payload* td = static_cast<Payload*>(targetData);
    *td = *sourceData;
    printPayload(*td);
}
```

Comment: @melpomene of course. It was a typo. Gonna edit the source. Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanWakely yes, I just wanted to keep the function as similar as possible to the original code. Gonna edit the source.

Answer (score 1):

You don't ever copy the source data to the target, but only change which object the targetData pointer points to.

Something like this would work:

```
Payload* targetPayload = reinterpret_cast<Payload*>(targetData);
*targetPayload = *sourceData;
```

Taking ownership of the source payload via a smart pointer is probably a bad idea - if the calling code is written to handle exceptions correctly, then it will delete the object on an error, so the smart pointer will mean it gets deleted twice. If the calling code is not written to handle exceptions correctly, then it's your job to write code which cannot throw an exception, which the smart pointer doesn't help with.

(as it's a cast between pointers, you could use static_cast, but I prefer reinterpret_cast as the void* could be *anything* and reinterpret_cast tells other developers something potentially dangerous is happening.)